# Does JAXB support inlined elements?

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson

I noticed that Jackson has a pending feature for inlined/unwrapped elements, see here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease19.

The idea is that you may have two classes:

```
class A {
    String y;
    String z;
}
class B {
    String x;
    A a;
}
```

And you want to produce JSON like:

```
{
    "x":"...",
    "y":"...",
    "z":"..."
}
```

The question is, does JAXB support some similar feature (or is it expected to at any point in the future)? I believe that normal inheritance can do this but since java doesn't support multiple inheritance this isn't always feasible (not to mention that the relationship might be more of a has-a rather than is-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([**JSR-222**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

MOXy currently supports this concept in its XML binding, and will support it in its JSON Binding via the `@XmlPath` extension (see below):

```
package forum7352753;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

class B {
    String x;
    A a;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @XmlPath(".")
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

**Enhancement Request**

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/357142

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

Comment: JAXB is a specification (JSR-222), and I am a member of the expert group.  Many people are familiar with the reference implementation which is included in Java SE 6, but there are others including EclipseLink MOXy and Apache JaxMe.  MOXy also contains extensions such as XPath based mapping.  My blog (http://blog.bdoughan.com) contains JAXB and MOXy examples if you are interested.

Comment: Ok so to get the desired functionality I'd have to swap out the standard jaxb implementation and then use extension features...hm...has there been any talk of standardizing this feature or something similar?

Comment: @Kevin - To get the desired functionality you would need to specify MOXy as your JAXB implementation (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).  MOXy is also a standard JAXB implementation since it passes the exact same certification tests as the reference implementation.  The `@XmlPath` extension is something I will be proposing to be included in future versions of the JAXB specification.